# How to change brightness from tty?

Tags: tty, xrandr, brightness

On Knsole(GUI) I executed

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 976
```

then the screen turned to almost a white board.  I can't use GUI any more. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, got a tty.
I want to reset brightness, but execute `xrandr` got

> can't not open display

Can I change brightness from tty?

Comment: Have you actually tried setting the display variable? e.g. `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 1.0`

Comment: Tried, but got `can't open display :0`

Comment: Well the primary X server display *may* be something other than `:0` - check with `ps -ef | grep '[X]org'` for example

Comment: Confirmed, it's :0 
`loginctl show-session c1 | grep Display`
`Display=:0`

Comment: @steeldriver Finanlly, found this works
 `su amtf -c "xrandr -d :0  --output HDMI1 --brightness 1"`

Comment: So the issue was that you were logging into the tty as a different user from that owning the display?

Comment: Yes, I use GUI as amtf, login tty as root.
I tried, if the same user in tty,  `su` can omit, use `-d :0 --output HDMI1 --brightness 1` is ok.

Comment: @AladinLee so your display is 0.0, try that. Go to raspberrypi.SE and be mauled by Milliways.

Comment: @steeldriver Haha you made me laugh with this discovery. +1

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

That will set brightness to 40%. You may need to change the directory to match your video card. Note also that you'll have to be in the `video` group.

`xbacklight` can be also helpful, e.g.

```
xbacklight -d :0 -dec 30
```

should decrease brightness by 30%.

---

Be aware that these two are hardware modification (people usually prefer that to manipulate screen brightness), and your initial command `xrandr --brightnes` uses software to manipulate gamma. The screen may or may not look exactly the same after applying these different techniques.

Comment: Awesome use of /sys. Although I'm pretty sure @steeldriver's command should also work.

Comment: I reboot and solved problem. I tried `xbacklight -d :0 -dec 30` in GUI, no error but nothing happened. Only `xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness .8` change brightness as expected.

Comment: @AladinLee How about `xbacklight -d :0 -set 10`?

Comment: Also no effect. And also change `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`  no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are using:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 976
```

is telling `xrandr` to set the brightness 976 times higher than normal.

- `1.0` sets to normal brightness
- `1.1` sets 10% above normal brightness but it's not recommended to go over 1.0 as colours wash out.
- `0.75` or `.75` sets to 75% of normal brightness
- `0.66` sets to 2/3 normal brightness, etc.